# Having trouble with reading csv values for a specific column using csv-parser

Tags: node.js, api, csv-parser

I am writing an api where I am sending back some data after a get request is being made. I am reading the data from a CSV file and then just sending back the data of a specific column name. The columns I have available are

```
[
  'YEAR',
  'TICKETS SOLD',
  'TOTAL BOX OFFICE',
  'TOTAL INFLATION ADJUSTED BOX OFFICE',
  'AVERAGE TICKET PRICE',
  ''
]
```

Here are some sample data from the Kaggle dataset I am using.

```
YEAR,TICKETS SOLD,TOTAL BOX OFFICE,TOTAL INFLATION ADJUSTED BOX OFFICE,AVERAGE TICKET PRICE,
2021,"42,37,74,881","$3,881,777,912","$3,881,777,912",$9.16,
2020,"22,36,38,958","$2,048,534,616","$2,048,534,616",$9.16,
2019,"1,22,85,41,629","$11,253,443,955","$11,253,444,050",$9.16,
```

I can read the data fine and can even display the data properly on the client side. Problem occurs when I try to access the `YEAR` field. For that specific field, I get `undefined` for all rows. That does not happen with the other fields. When I try to access the other fields, they return the value for each row correctly. I am not sure why this is happening.

This is my app.js (The main file)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Middleware

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/test'));
app.use('/movies', require('./routes/annualTicketSales'));

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Server Listening at ${port}`);
```

And this is my route file

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

let data = [];
fs.createReadStream('archive/AnnualTicketSales.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('headers', (headers) => {
        console.log(headers)
    })
    .on('data', async(d) => {
        console.log(d['YEAR']);                    // Returns Undefined for all the values
        console.log(d['AVERAGE TICKET PRICE']);    // Returns the correct value
        data.push(d);
    })
    .on('end', async() => {
        console.log("Successfully Read Data");
    });

route.get('/ticketSalesAnnual', async(req, res) => {
    return res.send(data);
})

module.exports = route;
```

As you can see, I am using fs and csv-parser to read the data. When I try to do `console.log(d['YEAR']);`, I get back undefined for each row. But when I use another header value, it returns the correct values for that column. I am not sure why this is happening, but can someone help me with this weird behavior?

Following is what I get for `console.log(headers)`

```
[
  'YEAR',
  'TICKETS SOLD',
  'TOTAL BOX OFFICE',
  'TOTAL INFLATION ADJUSTED BOX OFFICE',
  'AVERAGE TICKET PRICE',
  ''
]
```

The output in the console when I just do `console.log(d)` is as following

```
{
  'YEAR': '2021',
  'TICKETS SOLD': '42,37,74,881',
  'TOTAL BOX OFFICE': '$3,881,777,912',
  'TOTAL INFLATION ADJUSTED BOX OFFICE': '$3,881,777,912',
  'AVERAGE TICKET PRICE': '$9.16',
  '': ''
}
{
  'YEAR': '2020',
  'TICKETS SOLD': '22,36,38,958',
  'TOTAL BOX OFFICE': '$2,048,534,616',
  'TOTAL INFLATION ADJUSTED BOX OFFICE': '$2,048,534,616',
  'AVERAGE TICKET PRICE': '$9.16',
  '': ''
}
{
  'YEAR': '2019',
  'TICKETS SOLD': '1,22,85,41,629',
  'TOTAL BOX OFFICE': '$11,253,443,955',
  'TOTAL INFLATION ADJUSTED BOX OFFICE': '$11,253,444,050',
  'AVERAGE TICKET PRICE': '$9.16',
  '': ''
}
```

Following is the output when I use `console.log(d['YEAR])`

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Following is what I get for `console.log(d['AVERAGE TICKET PRICE']);`

```
$9.16
$9.16
$9.16
```

Comment: Take a look at the column headers that have been parsed out; `console.log(Object.keys(d))`. Is `YEAR` present? If not, you may want to inspect the data more closely.

Comment: I did that and `YEAR` is present. This is what it returns
`['YEAR','TICKETS SOLD','TOTAL BOX OFFICE','TOTAL INFLATION ADJUSTED BOX OFFICE','AVERAGE TICKET PRICE','']`

Comment: NVM! It was stupid of me. I did not realize that the file was encoded with utf-8 BOM. I removed that and it is working now. Thanks for suggesting to look into the data more closely @quickshiftin

Comment: in my case, I add one empty column at first with a header title and just skip it while parsing it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The file was encoded with UTF-8 BOM. I had to remove those. It is working now.